# why wont Unity wont let me use my script? (monobehaviour, compile error and script class issues)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I may well just be rather stupidly missing some easily fixable problem, but every time I try to add my script to a game object it stops me with the 'couldn't add script component 'Next' because script class could not be found' message. if I have the script in the project it give me a 'all compiler errors have to be fixed' message when I try and enter play mode. There is also a 'there is no MonoBehaviour scripts in the file, or their names do not match the file name' message when I click into it in the inspector. It is entirely possible that I messed up this piece of out of the box code, but I have done everything I could find. This is my first game and first time using c#, sorry. this is a basic code to make an object follow a player. (the filename is also Next)

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class Next : MonoBehaviour
   {
    public Transform target;
    NavMeshAgent nav;
    
    void Start()
   {
    nav = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
   }
   
   void Update 
   {
    nav.SetDestination(target.position)
   }
   }
```

tried renaming it, reimporting it and changing the part before MonoBehaviour to the file name

image 1. script component error
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xehvD.jpg

image 2. compile error
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbStX.jpg

image 3. no monobehaviour scripts
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xehvD.jpg

(I don't have the rep for embedded images yet sorry)

Comment: It seems obsessed with a file called example. I suggest you fix that

Comment: File name must match the class name.  If you have other compiler errors, those must be resolved as well before the entire assembly can be reloaded.

Comment: Can you add some screenshots of the error message?

Comment: @BugFinder apologies, that was just a placeholder name for the post, I have edited accordingly to show the actual file name (Next)

Comment: You need to look at the details of the errors in the console. Always fix the first error first some nay go if thats fixed.   All its telling us is you got something  wrong but not what

Comment: You are missing parenthesis at the end of Update method. Just add this "Update()".

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshots I can see that the `Update` method, the parenthesis are missing and is not recognised as a method.

Simply add "()" at the end of the Update. Your script should be like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class Next : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    NavMeshAgent nav;

    void Start()
    {
        nav = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    }

    void Update() 
    {
        nav.SetDestination(target.position)
    }
}
```